# How to call code located at second two sectors with NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

Maybe i'm stupid and doesn't know something but i think i'm doing it right. I have two files one *`boot.asm`*, second *`code.asm`*. At *`boot.asm`* i just enable video mode fill screen with blue color and try to load code located at two seconds sectors, but when i try it nothing just happen and can't get out what i'm doing wrong, maybe i reading wrong or *`code.asm`* is wrong coded or *`boot.asm`* is wrong coded. Why i can't call code stored in two second sectors to complete them.

For more information i going to load this code from MBR and i want to my code call code at two second sectors because i can't fit them all in one sector, so i asking this question.

> **boot.asm**
>
> ```
> ;bootloader
>   bits 16
>   org 0x7c00
>
> ;Here i try to load code located at second two sectors
> Load_Code:    
>     ;---Setup segments
>     xor ax, ax                  ; AX=0
>     mov ds, ax                  ; DS=ES=0 because we use an org of 0x7c00 - Segment<<4+offset = 0x0000<<4+0x7c00 = 0x07c00
>     mov ax, es
>     mov ax, ss
>     mov sp, 0x7c00              ; SS:SP= 0x0000:0x7c00 stack just below bootloader
>
>   ;---Read 2 sectors
>   mov bx, buffer              ; ES: BX must point to the buffer
>   mov dh,0                    ; head number
>   mov ch,0                    ; track number
>   mov cl,2                    ; sector number
>   mov al,2                    ; number of sectors to read
>   mov ah,2                    ; read function number
>   int 13h
>
> ;Graphics mode
> Set_Video:
>   mov ax, 12h        ; Graphics mode (640x480x16)
>   int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
>   mov ah, 06h        ; Scroll up function
>   xor al, al         ; Clear entire screen
>   xor cx, cx         ; Upper left corner CH=row, CL=column
>   mov dx, 3FFFh      ; fill whole screen
>   mov bh, 11h        ; blue background 
>   int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>   call buffer
>
> ;Endless loop
> .endloop:
>   hlt
>   jmp .endloop
>
>
> ;Fake MBR signature
> MBR_Signature:
>   times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
>   dw 0xAA55
>
> buffer:
> ```

---

> **code.asm** *- second two sectors that contains this code - (this is just example code)*
>
> ```
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 0          ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 0          ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 1          ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 1          ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 2          ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 2          ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 3          ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 3          ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 4          ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 4          ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 5          ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 5          ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 6          ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 6          ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 7          ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 7          ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 8          ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 8          ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 9          ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 9          ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 10         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 10         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 11         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 11         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 12         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 12         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 13         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 13         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 14         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 14         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 15         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 15         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 16         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 16         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 17         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 17         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 18         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 18         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 19         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 19         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 20         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 20         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 21         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 21         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 22         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 22         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 23         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 23         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 24         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 24         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 25         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 25         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 26         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 26         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 27         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 27         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 28         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 28         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 29         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 29         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 30         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 30         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 31         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 31         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 32         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 32         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 33         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 33         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 34         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 34         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 35         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 35         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 36         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 36         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 37         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 37         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 38         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 38         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 39         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 39         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 40         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 40         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 41         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 41         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 42         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 42         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 43         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 43         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 44         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 44         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 45         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 45         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 46         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 46         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 47         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 47         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 48         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 48         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 49         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 49         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 50         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 50         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 51         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 51         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 52         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 52         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 53         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 53         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 54         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 54         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 55         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 55         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 56         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 56         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 57         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 57         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 58         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 58         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 59         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 59         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 60         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 60         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 61         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 61         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 62         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 62         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 63         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 63         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 64         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 64         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 65         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 65         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 66         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 66         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 67         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 67         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 68         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 68         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 69         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 69         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 70         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 70         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 71         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 71         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 72         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 72         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 73         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 73         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 74         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 74         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 75         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 75         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 76         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 76         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 77         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 77         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 78         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 78         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 79         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 79         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 80         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 80         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 81         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 81         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 82         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 82         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 83         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 83         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> mov al, 15         ; color - white
> mov ah, 0ch        ; set pixel
> mov cx, 84         ; x co-ordinate
> mov dx, 84         ; y co-ordinate
> int 10h            ; BIOS draw function
>
> ret
> times 1024 - ($ - $$) db 0x00
> ```

[How it look like in hex.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su5eh.png)

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong at first glance. Use a debugger. Also, add error handling. Furthermore, add some ending and if you want to troubleshoot loading then don't mess with graphics. I have done that and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: `buffer` doesn't end with a `ret` to return to the pointer after the `call`

Comment: Also noticed that all your segment register settings are reversed `mov ax, ds` should be `mov ds,ax` same thing applies for es and ss.

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step this; BOCHS has one built-in.

Comment: i don't understood where i have to add `ret` it in `boot.asm` or `code.asm`?

Comment: You also clobber DL that had the drive number when you did `mov dx, 0x3fff` . You could `push `dx` before you modify DX and then `pop dx` after the `int 10h` or move DX into another register temporarily and move it back. Either way you need to save DX before youmodify it so that the disk reads have the proper boot drive number later on in DL

Comment: As for the `ret` it should be placed after the last line of code in `code.asm` and before the `times` directive in `code.asm`

Comment: The alternative to saving and restoring DX is to load the disk sectors before you do the graphics work.

Comment: @MichaelPetch looks like my first glance wasn't all that thorough :)

Comment: I have to apologize. I realized the segment setting code looked rather familiar.It came from this answer I wrote this past week: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51583105/3857942  . I mistakenly in haste was responsible for that mess. I was the one who wrote them backwards and people used the code. I have fixed that mistake in that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of your problem is that you are clobbering the contents of `dl` when you clear the screen.

When BIOS loads your boot sector and then calls it, it puts the drive number into `dl`.  You must preserve this value for use when you attempt, later, to load in the subsequent sectors into memory.  Since you fail to do so, when you attempt to read the drive, BIOS is trying to read from a (likely) non-existent device.

Comment: Yes you are right, but how do i clear screen without clobbering the contents of `dl`?
I can't fist load sectors and then clear screen, i have to clean screen first and don't ask why.

Comment: The absolutely simplest way to do it is to either define the stack first and push it there or define where DS is and store it in your code segment somewhere out of the way. :)

Comment: now my stack is 128kb big and i have to load it 4 times with 32kb and when i define it at start i can't run it later, because 16bit mode limit is 64k, so it complete only for 50%. And i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: It sounds like you are moving on to other questions. :) I'm not clear on why you think you need such a large stack, though...

Comment: because i in this big stack i stored code that draw image pixel by pixel.

Comment: Why are you putting your code in the stack?  Load it into a memory location and jump to it.

Comment: ok, but i have only one problem i am limited with 64 sectors, but my code is 256 sectors big and i can't load 4 times by 64kb, because after fist call i am unable to read next 64sectors.

Comment: You ought to start a new question for that. ;)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> xor ax, ax                  ; AX=0
> mov ds, ax                  ; DS=ES=0 because we use an org of 0x7c00 - Segment<<4+offset = 0x0000<<4+0x7c00 = 0x07c00
> mov ax, es
> mov ax, ss
> mov sp, 0x7c00
> ```

Setting up the segment registers fails!

You need to store `AX` **in** them and not the other way.

```
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax                    <---
mov ss, ax                    <---
mov sp, 0x7c00
```

---

> ```
> mov ah, 0x07        ; function to call with interrupt
> mov bh, 0x01        ; blue background 
> mov dx, 0x3FFF      ; fill whole screen
> int 0x10            ; BIOS draw function
> ```

How you paint the screen 12h is rather strange!

This screen has 80 columns and 30 rows, so the lower right corner is at (79,29).
You also forgot to specify the upperleft corner which is (0,0). Your bootloader program should never rely on `CX` having a zero value when the program starts!

```
mov ah, 0x07        ; function to call with interrupt
mov bh, 0x01        ; blue background 
xor cx, cx          ; (0,0)                       <-----
mov dx, 0x1D4F      ; (79,29)                     <-----
int 0x10            ; BIOS draw function
```

Comment: I'm solely responsible for the segment operations being done in the wrong direction. I realized the segment setting code looked rather familiar.It came from this answer I wrote this past week: http://stackoverflow.com/a/51583105/3857942 . I was the one who wrote them backwards and people used the code. I have fixed that mistake in that answer. Until a little while ago I didn't realize it.