# assembly protected mode not work on real hardware

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, bootloader

i've tryied to create my own OS in assembly.
i learned real mode (16 bit) and now i'm learning protected mode (32 bit)

in the QEMU emulator the OS works perfectly but when i load it on my computer (32 bit) it doesn't work.

this is the code:

```
   [org 0x7c00]        

   xor ax, ax
   mov ds, ax
   mov es, ax
   mov bp, 0x8000
   mov sp, bp

   mov ah, 0x0
   mov al, 0x3
   int 0x10
   
   
   CODE_SEG equ GDT_code - GDT_start
   DATA_SEG equ GDT_data - GDT_start
   
   cli
   lgdt [GDT_descriptor]
   mov eax, cr0
   or eax, 1
   mov cr0, eax
   jmp CODE_SEG:start_protected_mode
   
   ;jmp $
                                
                                 
   GDT_start:                          ; must be at the end of real mode code
       GDT_null:
          dd 0x0
          dd 0x0
         
       GDT_code:
          dw 0xffff
          dw 0x0
          db 0x0
          db 0b10011010
          db 0b11001111
          db 0x0
       
       GDT_data:
          dw 0xffff
          dw 0x0
          db 0x0
          db 0b10010010
          db 0b11001111
          db 0x0
        
   GDT_end:

   GDT_descriptor:
       dw GDT_end - GDT_start - 1
       dd GDT_start
     
   [bits 32]
   start_protected_mode:
       mov ax, DATA_SEG
       mov ss, ax
       mov ds, ax
       mov es, ax
       mov fs, ax
       mov gs, ax
       mov ebp, 0x90000
       mov esp, ebp
        
       mov al, 'A'
       mov ah, byte 0x02
       mov [0xb8000], ax
       hlt 
       jmp $
       
     times 510-($-$$) db 0              
     dw 0xaa55
```

and for the compilation I use these commands:

```
nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o boot.bin
qemu-system-x86_64 boot.bin
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: How does it not work, how do you boot it (usb drive, hard disk, floppy, cdrom), does the real mode part start at least (put something in there)?

Comment: i boot it from USB. the computer when loading the Bootloader shows nothing and restarts. the real mode start at the beginning

Comment: Does it work if you stay in real mode? Such as `mov ax, 0xb800; mov ds, ax; mov word [0], 0x0241; jmp $`?

Comment: yes, it works. so where is the problem?

Comment: Are you booting this on a real computer with a USB stick using Floppy Disk Emulation (FDD)?

Comment: Best keep setting `ss` and `sp` close together: `mov ss, ax` `mov sp, bp` (Real mode) and `mov ss, ax` `mov esp, ebp` (Protected mode). You forgot to set `ss` in the real mode part!

Comment: @MichaelPetch no, i am booting this from a normally usb stick using "balenaetcher"

Comment: If the BIOS is set to boot USB media as floppy media then this could be a problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320115/3857942