# My assembly code for printing string works on QEMU, but not on real hardwares

Tags: assembly, nasm, qemu, real-mode

I want to make an OS, but it works only in a way, Cosmos C# make me a bunch of errors for only an iso, where is the error here?

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

start:
    mov si, msg
    call printer
    jmp $

printer:
    mov ah, 0x0E
.prntloop:
    lodsb
    or al,al
    jz .done
    int 10h
    jmp .prntloop
.done:
    ret

msg db "Hello World!", 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

I'm using **NASM** as a compiler.
Thanks.

I've tried this on my real hardware, such as an laptop, the thing that happens when booted finally is that teleports cursor and then casually beeps

Comment: You forgot to set up `ds`. Also you might need a BPB.

Comment: Where is the stack pointer `sp` pointing to?

Comment: How i can set that ds?

Comment: And? How i can set a BpB?

Comment: Info on a BPB is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320115/3857942 and general bootloader tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701854/boot-loader-doesnt-jump-to-kernel-code/32705076#32705076

Comment: My laptop if i go to boot menu without a bpb, it recognizes as a diskette drive

Comment: Presumably a duplicate of [Boot loader doesn't jump to kernel code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076) (bootloader tips) if fixing those likely showstopper problems doesn't help, then it can get reopened.  @MichaelPetch: Is there a simpler canonical about setting DS to match ORG so you can access your own static data?  Your bootloader-tips FAQ is about loading more sectors.

Comment: @ndim: AFAIK, real BIOSes *do* set SS:SP pointing at some amount of usable stack space, enough to at least call simple `int` BIOS functions and run interrupt handlers.  Maybe not *much* space, but some.  You don't have to set SS:SP unless you're loading more sectors (or otherwise storing outside the 512 bytes of your own boot sector) and need to make sure you're not clashing with the BIOS's choice of linear address for the initial stack.

Comment: I've added BPB, but remains the same :(

Comment: If you added a BPB, did you also set DS to 0 (since you use org 0x7c00). At the start of your code (at `main` if you used my BPB) do something like `xor ax, ax` `mov ds, ax`

Comment: @MichaelPetch THANK YOU SO MUCH, ITS FIXED, YOU'RE A GENIUSS