# Why Stage 2 works on QEMU, but on real hardwares nothing?

Tags: assembly, memory, nasm

I'm trying to load on memory the Stage 2, ive added a flag that shows error, works on qemu, but on real hardwares, the error flag isnt showing and im thinking that loaded successfully, but nothing appears. I've added a BPB also.

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16

boot:
    jmp main
    TIMES 3-($-$$) DB 0x90   ; Support 2 or 3 byte encoded JMPs before BPB.

    ; Dos 4.0 EBPB 1.44MB floppy
    OEMname:           db    "mkfs.fat"  ; mkfs.fat is what OEMname mkdosfs uses
    bytesPerSector:    dw    512
    sectPerCluster:    db    1
    reservedSectors:   dw    1
    numFAT:            db    2
    numRootDirEntries: dw    224
    numSectors:        dw    2880
    mediaType:         db    0xf0
    numFATsectors:     dw    9
    sectorsPerTrack:   dw    18
    numHeads:          dw    2
    numHiddenSectors:  dd    0
    numSectorsHuge:    dd    0
    driveNum:          db    0
    reserved:          db    0
    signature:         db    0x29
    volumeID:          dd    0x2d7e5a1a
    volumeLabel:       db    "NO NAME    "
    fileSysType:       db    "FAT12   "

main:
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax

; Pause for making stable the reading...
mov ah, 0x00
int 16h

mov ah, 0x02
mov al, 1
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 2
mov dh, 0
mov dl, 0x00
mov bx, stage_two
int 13h
jc on_error

jmp stage_two

printer:
    mov ah, 0x0E
.prntloop:
    lodsb
    or al,al
    jz .done
    int 10h
    jmp .prntloop
.done:
    ret

on_error:
mov si, errorstr
call printer
jmp $

errorstr db "Error.", 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

stage_two:
mov ah, 0Eh
mov al, 'A'
int 10h
jmp $

times 1024-($-$$) db 0
```

Tried on my laptop, the usb is blinking and loads correctly, but nothing happens

Comment: I notice you don't set ES, but `int 13h`/AH=2 takes a pointer in ES:BX.  So ES should be set like DS, to match your `org`.   Also, you don't set SS:SP to a known location so you don't know whether your sector loads might be overwriting the stack.  [Custom bootloader booted via USB drive produces incorrect output on some computers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320115) / [Boot loader doesn't jump to kernel code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076) - the first point in that answer is about the same bug you have, not setting ES, so looks like a duplicate.  Also has other general tips.

Comment: I don't know where to put these values, can u help me? i'm a beginner

Comment: [Boot loader doesn't jump to kernel code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32701854) explains the details. You're already setting DS at the top of your code, `mov es, ax` as well.